# How much smoke does a smoker exhale each breath?

Tags: word-problem

I'm honestly not sure if this is a calculus question as much as it is a biology question, but I figured MSE will tell me either way.

If I inhale 100 units of smoke, I will exhale less than that amount. Say, for example, that I still have 5 units in my lungs. When I inhale and exhale again there will be some proportion of that 5 units left and so on. How much smoke, as a proportion of the initial 100 units, do I still have inside me after $n$ subsequent breaths?

EDIT: we concluded that the amount of smoke left in the lungs after $n$ breaths is in the form $S^{-n}$.  Is there some means of now finding $S$? Surely now we are closer to the realm of biology than maths.

Comment: Seriously though: don't smoke

Comment: Not the point of the question :p

Answer (score 1):

Look at it in terms of concentration: after taking one breath, the amount of smoke remaining is $\frac1{20}$ of the amount that was there before the breath. So after $n$ breaths, the proportion of smoke remaining to the initial amount of smoke is $\frac1{20^n}$.

Exactly this kind of problem comes up in chemistry, when an initial stock solution is [serially diluted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_dilution) and the final concentration (i.e. molarity) must be calculated.

Comment: Perfect! The chemistry analogy was exactly what my brain needed to make sense of the problem

Comment: @SupBro I must note that I did honours in chemistry in high school (organic, inorganic, AP, spectroscopy, etc.), so that's why that came to my mind quickly.